# Get a list from numpy ndarray in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray here which I am trying to convert it to a list.

```
>>> a=np.array([[[0.7]], [[0.3]], [[0.5]]])
```

I am using hstack for it. However, I am getting a list of a list. How can I get a list instead? I am expecting to get `[0.7, 0.3, 0.5]`.

```
>>> b = np.hstack(a)
>>> b
array([[0.7, 0.3, 0.5]])
```

Comment: Use: `a.ravel().tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand what you have?

```
In [46]: a=np.array([[[0.7]], [[0.3]], [[0.5]]])    
In [47]: a
Out[47]: 
array([[[0.7]],

       [[0.3]],

       [[0.5]]])    
In [48]: a.shape
Out[48]: (3, 1, 1)
```

That's a 3d array - count the []

You can convert it to 1d with:

```
In [49]: a.ravel()
Out[49]: array([0.7, 0.3, 0.5])
```

`tolist` converts the array to a list:

```
In [50]: a.ravel().tolist()
Out[50]: [0.7, 0.3, 0.5]
```

You could also use `a[:,0,0]`.  If you use `hstack`, that partially flattens it - but not all the way to 1d.

```
In [51]: np.hstack(a)
Out[51]: array([[0.7, 0.3, 0.5]])
In [52]: _.shape
Out[52]: (1, 3)
In [53]: np.hstack(a)[0]
Out[53]: array([0.7, 0.3, 0.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, [`numpy.ndarray.flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) can be used:

```
a.flatten().tolist()
```

---

And yet another possibility:

```
a.reshape(-1).tolist()
```

---

Output:

```
[0.7, 0.3, 0.5]
```